# Showing an identity for the range of a linear map (commutative diagram)

Tags: linear-algebra

We look at a linear map $f$ and this commutative diagram:

[image: diagram]

$a$ and $b$ are isomorphisms and $c$ is also a linear map with the property that one can describe $f$ with $b^{-1}\circ c \circ a$.

How can I Show that $\text{im } c$ and $\text{im }f$ have the same Dimension?

The book suggests that the map $b$ is an isomorphism between the two vectorspaces but I don't know how I can prove it.

What this basically means is that the map $z:\text{im }f\rightarrow \text{im }c$ with $z(x)=b(x)$ is isomorph.

Fist of all we would have to explain that this map, to be precise the assigning-rule is well defined. If we take an element $x$ from $\text{im} f$ then we Always get $b(x)\in \text{im }c$. How can I Show this?

If this is done then we would be finished because linearity and bijectivity follows from the fact that $b$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Your statement "a and b are isomorphisms" means that both a and b are isomorphisms between two vector spaces

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $b$ is an isomorphism between $W$ and $Y$ but it does not necessatily mean that the subspaces $im $f and $im $ c of $W$ and $V$ respectively are isomorph to each other

Comment: +1 for artistic value.

Comment: Not related:I don't know how to write commutative diagrams in Latex, I think you Need an extra package. Otherwise if there would be a template I could copy-paste I would do this instead

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in im f$ we want to Show there exists a $n\in X$ such that $c(n)=b(x)$, i.e $b(x)\in imc$.

We know there exists a $v\in V$ such that $f(v)=x$, also using the identity of $f$ from the commutative diagram we get.

$b(x)=b(f(v))=b(b^{-1}(c(a(v))))=c(a(v))$

So we pick for our $n$ the $a(v)$